# Is there anyway to do write functions that return both an answer and an exit code in Python?

Tags: python

For purpose of illustration, in pseudocode:

```
function addint(x,y,answer: integer)
  var
    condition: integer;

  begin
    if ((MAXINT - x) < y) then
      begin
        answer := x;
        condition := 1;    
      end
     else
       begin
         answer := x + y;
         condition := 0;
       end;  

     return condition;
   end.
```

In the example, answer is either called by reference or is a pointer. It holds the actual result to be passed back to the caller, and the function itself holds the exit code. The exit code follows the C tradition: 0 for normal exit and other values for abnormal exit. It is required because the operation is not always successful, depending on the values of x and y.

Is there anyway to write the same style of functions in Python without major modifications?

Comment: Return a tuple of values or an object...? Typically though you *raise an exception* if something goes wrong, you don't return a "falsey value" like `1`.

Comment: Multiple return arguments are usually handled by returning a tuple. After that, caller can do whatever he wants with those return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write functions that return multiple values in Python. Briefly,

```
def test():
    return 1, 2

x, y = test() #=> x = 1, y = 2
```

Comment: Technically it returns single value (a tuple). But language has convenient syntactic sugar (iterable packing / unpacking) so it almost feel like you are returning multiple values.